# Filtering fusion tables using where clause

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to filter a fusion table using the WHERE clause in order to display land areas below a certain size. I am not sure if it is a simple problem with the syntax but this filter will not work for me.  Here is the code:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

query: {

select: 'Geometry',

from: 4310315,

where: 'rollingarea' < 400,


  }
});
```

I have tried different variations such as where 'rollingarea < 40' & "'rollingarea' < 400" but cant get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your [table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=4310315), the column name is "ROLLING AREA".

Try:
["'ROLLING AREA' < 400"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=55.134627&lng=-7.702476&zoom=9&type=m&tableid=4310315&tablequery=select%20geometry%20from%204310315%20where%20%22%27ROLLING%20AREA%27%20%3C%20400%22)

Comment: One more question, is it possible to filter fusion tables in the following way;      where:  "'ROLLING AREA' < numberinput" ?                    (in this instance numberinput is a variable which is entered by the user in a textbox eg. user inputs 300 or 400 etc depending on the quantity of land they would like to be displayed on the map)

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.  You need to get the value out of the text box and concatenate it with your query (be careful with the quotes...)